# dojo/date/locale/format formats correctly, but returns the wrong date?

Tags: javascript, date, dojo

```
value = date.locale.format(dte, {
   datePattern : "MMMM d, yyyy",
   selector : 'date'
});
```

dte = "2012-12-21"

value = "December 20, 2012"

Is this really the end of days that DoJo doesn't even know what 21st is? Really though...why is it converting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is presumably a timezone thing, depending on how you instantiate `dte`. "2012-12-21" is quite ambiguous.

For example, I'm in UTC+1, so the following code would have the same "problem" for me:

```
dte = new Date("Fri, 21 Dec 2012 23:01:00 GMT");

value = date.locale.format(dte, {
   datePattern : "MMMM d, yyyy",
   selector : 'date'
});
```

Value would show "Dec 22, 2012" for me in this case, because my computer time is UTC+1.